# Finding an optimal trajectory

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

I want to find the optimal control and optimal trajectory for the following problem:

min $J(u) = \int_{0}^{T} [x_1^2+x_2^2+5u^2]dt$ subject to $\dot{x_1} = x_2$, $\dot{x_2} = u$, and $|u| \leq 1$.

Now, let's first write the Hamiltonian and find the conditions to be satisfied:

$H = x_1^2+x_2^2+5u^2 + p_1x_2 + p_2u$

For the costate p, we have: $\dot{p} = -\nabla_xH$

$\dot{p_1} = -2x_1$

$\dot{p_2} = 2x_2 + p_1$

For the state x, we have: $\dot{x} = \nabla_pH$

$\dot{x_1} = x_2$

$\dot{x_2} = u$

For optimal control: $u^*(t) =\mathrm{argmin}_{|u| \leq 1}$ $x_1^2+x_2^2+5u^2 + p_1x_2 + p_2u$
\begin{equation}
u^*(t) =
\begin{cases}
    -1,&\text{if } p_2(t)\geq 10\\\\
    \frac{-p_2(t)}{10},  &\text{if } 10 \geq p_2(t)\geq -10\\\\
     1,              &p_2(t)\leq -10 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I could not figure out how to solve these equations to get the optimal trajectory $x(t)$. It seems somehow I should get $p_2(t)$ but how?

Comment: Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: @KBS I think it is from optimal control systems by Desineni Subbaram Naidu

Comment: Which problem exactly?

Comment: @KBS, problem 2.8. But in the book the final state is given, in here it is not given.

Comment: @KBS, check the book's link here: http://mu.menofia.edu.eg/PrtlFiles/Staff/1045/Portal/Files/optimal%20control%20systems.pdf

Comment: @eet you need to use equation (2.8.44) on page 90.